# quartz and spring upgrade is having issues around abstract class/bean

Tags: java, spring, maven, quartz

One of our apps is upgrading Spring from 2.5.6 to 4.2.5 and quartz 1.6.5 to 2.2.2.
I have been working to resolve issues one by one but i'm down to this one that I can't seem to work out.

The error is:

```
2017-04-03 14:52:47,570 INFO {main} [org.quartz.core.QuartzScheduler] - Scheduler meta-data: Quartz Scheduler (v2.2.2) 'PvScheduler' with instanceId 'NON_CLUSTERED'
  Scheduler class: 'org.quartz.core.QuartzScheduler' - running locally.
  NOT STARTED.
  Currently in standby mode.
  Number of jobs executed: 0
  Using thread pool 'org.quartz.simpl.SimpleThreadPool' - with 10 threads.
  Using job-store 'org.quartz.simpl.RAMJobStore' - which does not support persistence. and is not clustered.

2017-04-03 14:52:47,572 INFO {main} [org.quartz.impl.StdSchedulerFactory] - Quartz scheduler 'PvScheduler' initialized from an externally provided properties instance.
2017-04-03 14:52:47,574 INFO {main} [org.quartz.impl.StdSchedulerFactory] - Quartz scheduler version: 2.2.2
2017-04-03 14:52:47,576 INFO {main} [org.quartz.core.QuartzScheduler] - JobFactory set to: org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.AdaptableJobFactory@749ad37c
*** SaPvApp: Registering JVM shutdown hook
*** SaPvApp: version 17.1.0
*** SaPvApp: Adding service-stop event listeners
*** SaPvApp: Starting service at Mon Apr 03 14:52:47 CDT 2017
*** SaPvApp: Unexpected service error at Mon Apr 03 14:52:47 CDT 2017
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanIsAbstractException: Error creating bean with name 'intAppService': Bean definition is abstract
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.checkMergedBeanDefinition(AbstractBeanFactory.java:1288)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:285)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBean(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1054)
        at AbstractCommandLineApplication.runApplication(AbstractCommandLineApplication.java:112)
        at AbstractCommandLineApplication.runApplication(AbstractCommandLineApplication.java:54)
        at cmd.SaPvApp.main(SaPvApp.java:18)
*** SaPvApp: Calling service stop event listeners
*** SaPvApp: Exiting service at Mon Apr 03 14:52:47 CDT 2017
*** SaPvApp ShutdownHook: Service shutdown initiated at Mon Apr 03 14:52:47 CDT 2017
*** SaPvApp ShutdownHook: Closing application context
2017-04-03 14:52:47,609 INFO {ApplicationShutdownHook} [org.springframework.context.support.FileSystemXmlApplicationContext] - Closing org.springframework.context.support.FileSystemXmlApplicationContext@63e31ee: startup date [Mon Apr 03 14:52:41 CDT 2017]; root of context hierarchy
2017-04-03 14:52:47,615 INFO {ApplicationShutdownHook} [org.springframework.context.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor] - Stopping beans in phase 2147483647
2017-04-03 14:52:47,618 INFO {ApplicationShutdownHook} [org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.SchedulerFactoryBean] - Shutting down Quartz Scheduler
2017-04-03 14:52:47,619 INFO {ApplicationShutdownHook} [org.quartz.core.QuartzScheduler] - Scheduler PvScheduler_$_NON_CLUSTERED shutting down.
2017-04-03 14:52:47,620 INFO {ApplicationShutdownHook} [org.quartz.core.QuartzScheduler] - Scheduler PvScheduler_$_NON_CLUSTERED paused.
2017-04-03 14:52:47,621 INFO {ApplicationShutdownHook} [org.quartz.core.QuartzScheduler] - Scheduler PvScheduler_$_NON_CLUSTERED shutdown complete.
*** SaPvApp ShutdownHook: Service shutdown complete
```

here is my spring context file:

```
<bean name="intAppService" class="QuartzTaskScheduler" init-method="listen" abstract="true">
    <property name="name" value="PvJobListener" />
    <property name="quartzScheduler" ref="quartzScheduler"/>
</bean>

<bean name="quartzScheduler" class="org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.SchedulerFactoryBean">
    <property name="autoStartup" value="false" />
    <property name="schedulerName" value="PvScheduler" />
    <property name="triggers">
        <list>
            <ref bean="cronTrigger" />
        </list>
    </property>
</bean>

<bean id="jobDetail" class="org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.MethodInvokingJobDetailFactoryBean">
    <property name="targetObject" ref="serviceTask" />
    <property name="targetMethod" value="run" />
    <property name="concurrent" value="false" />
    <property name="group" value="PV" />
    <property name="name" value="${app.service.name}${app.service.instance}-Job" />
    <!--<property name="jobListenerNames">
        <list>
            <value>PvJobListener</value>
        </list>
    </property>-->
</bean>

<bean id="cronTrigger" class="org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.CronTriggerFactoryBean">
    <property name="jobDetail" ref="jobDetail" />
    <!--<property name="cronExpression" value="10 0/01 * * * ?"  />-->
    <!-- run twice a day at 3am and 3pm -->
     <property name="cronExpression" value="0 0 3,15 ? * *"  />
    <!-- run every 30 minutes, at 10 seconds after the minute (i.e. 10:00:10 am, 10:30:10 am, etc.) 
    <property name="cronExpression" value="10 0/30 * * * ?"  />  -->
</bean>
```

edit 4/4/17 07:59:
I tried creating a parent abstract class

```
    <bean name="intAppServiceParent" abstract = "true">
    <property name="nameParent" value="PvJobListenerParent" />
    <property name="quartzSchedulerParent" ref="quartzSchedulerParent"/>
</bean>

<bean name="intAppService" class="QuartzTaskScheduler" init-method="listen" parent = "intAppServiceParent">
    <property name="name" value="PvJobListener" />
    <property name="quartzScheduler" ref="quartzScheduler"/>
</bean>
```

but I'm getting this error:

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'intAppService' defined in file [C:\Integration Apps\SAPV\config\SaPvApp-context.xml]: Instantiation of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [QuartzTaskScheduler]: Is it an abstract class?; nested exception is java.lang.InstantiationException
```

If I don't make the java code class abstract I get a compile error about this:

```
The type QuartzTaskScheduler must implement the inherited abstract method SchedulerListener.triggersPaused(String)
```

I'm not sure how to fix this?

Comment: Where you defined the PvScheduler property?

Comment: @fabfas
it's in the quartzScheduler bean.

Comment: @fabfas are you saying that bean should be abstract as well?

Comment: You are referencing the `intAppService` somewhere (or maybe due to the `init` method)... The bean is marked as `abstract` and as such an instance cannot be created, you can only use this definition as `parent` to other beans.

Comment: @M.Deinum
I updated the OP. I tried creating parent bean that was abstract then referencing it in the main bean but it's still complaining. Any ideas on how to fix?

Comment: @M.Deinum
actually I think I may have fixed it and am testing now. The issue was around QuartzTaskScheduler since the upgrade the code did not implement all the abstract methods. I had to implement them all. It is probably because its parent class has been changed, so new abstract methods were added, or signatures of some methods were changed. 
I will remember to post full stack from now on. I'm new to the community and need tips like that. :)

Comment: @M.Deinum
Also, would you mind editing your comment and removing the company name. I missed it and my find/replace and should not have included it in the OP I believe I have it removed in the OP now. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The issue was around QuartzTaskScheduler since the upgrade the code did not implement all the abstract methods. I had to implement them all. It is probably because its parent class has been changed, so new abstract methods were added, or signatures of some methods were changed.